# Combine two separate sql queries into single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql queries

```
SELECT sub_id, 
       sub_sent_code, 
       date_time 
FROM   moviedatabase.reg_sub_master 
WHERE  (date_time >= '2013-01-19' 
         AND date_time <= '2013-01-29');
```

and

```
SELECT sub_id, 
       sub_sent_code, 
       date_time 
FROM   moviedatabase.reg_sub_master 
WHERE  date_time <= '2013-01-19';
```

My requirment is from 1st query what ever the result comes that `sub_id,sub_sent_code,date_time` should not be present in 2nd query .

I want to make it single query.

**EDIT** : actually i want the result where `date_time >='2013-01-19'` AND `date_time <='2013-01-29'` and the `sub_id` which i am getting should not the be there before `'2013-01-19'`

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
SELECT sub_id,sub_sent_code,date_time
FROM   moviedatabase.reg_sub_master
WHERE  (date_time >='2013-01-19' 
    AND date_time <='2013-01-29')
    AND sub_id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT sub_id
        FROM   moviedatabase.reg_sub_master
        WHERE  date_time <='2013-01-19;
```

Comment: actually i want the result where date_time >='2013-01-19' 
    AND date_time <='2013-01-29'     and the sub_id which i am getting should not the be there  before '2013-01-19'

Comment: That seems to mean that all sub-id existing between 01-19 and 01-29 are found before.